# Ajax/XML Parsing - How can I get only the parent's attribute when the child has the same attr?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

```
<parent>
  <name></name>
  <color></color>
    <child>
      <name></name>
    </child>
</parent>
```

How can I only get the parent name but not the child name?

So far I have this but it returns both name attributes.

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("parent").each(function()
  {
    $("#id").append($(this).find("name").text()+ "<br />");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead of find()

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("parent").each(function()
    {
         $("#id").append($(this).children("name").text()+ "<br />");
    });
 }
```

**Updated**

This will remove the child text and return only parent text

```
$(xml).find("parent").each(function()
{
     alert($(this).clone().find("child").remove().end().text()+ "<br />");
});​
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3D3f/)

Comment: but I don't want the child attribute - only the parent.